# Cucumber with IntelliJ not finding step definitions

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

I encountered the following issue. I have four Cucumber feature files in IntelliJ. I added the Cucumber support via the IntelliJ plugin. After creating my features I edited my configuration like followed so i can execute the feature files.

[image: This is how my configuration looks like]
Glue should be the name of the package the step definitions reside in. In my case the package is called **stepdefinitions**.

The following image shows what my project structure looks like. The feature files reside in **/src/test/resource/features** while the stepdefinitions are stored in **/src/test/java/stepdefinitions**.
[image: This is how my project structure looks like]

Sadly when I try to run the cucumber features with the step definitions I get prompted *"You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:"* But I already did this. I already copied those snippets to the step definition files. When I hover a scenario IntelliJ tells me *Unimplemented Substep Definition".

[image: Unimplemented Substep Defintion]

Those two things lead me to the conclusion that IntelliJ does not find my step definitions. Maybe one of you knows what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your `Glue` setting should point to the java classes, not your step defintions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my question. The error was caused by a plugin called **Substep IntelliJ Plugin**. You need to search for it in the IntelliJ Plugin Section and disable or deinstall it.

Comment: I was also had this issue.

Comment: This solution didn't help me. Substep IntelliJ Plugin was disabled. I uninstalled it, restarted Intellij. It didn't help: steps in .feature files are still not recognized.

Comment: I do not see any plugin with name Substep IntelliJ Plugin installed in my Intellij. I still cann't locate the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Invalidate cache and restart'. It worked for me - something the plugin gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to delete & recreate the Run Configuration.

I was clicking the "Run" from the Feature file, and it kept failing.  As soon as, I ran it from the Runner class, it worked. Then I looked into Run Configurations, and IntelliJ was running old run profile before I had changed the package name. I deleted all Run Configurations for Cucumber features. Clicked Run on the Feature again, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Cucumber plugin to avoid collisions over feature file association, install the Substeps plugin. See http://substeps.github.io/ for more docs on how to use the Substeps BDD framework alongside downloading a sample starter project from here: https://github.com/Substeps/substeps-example/archive/1.1.zip