# IntelliJ Cucumber-Jave step definition not recognised

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-java

This looks like common issue. I have tried most of solutions on the web. Unfortunately non of them worked for me. I am using IntelliJ 2019.3 Ultimate edition

Cucumber-Java (bundle) and Gherkin (bundle) plugins already there.

Solutions tried:

1. [Check SubType IntelliJ plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307632/cucumber-with-intellij-not-finding-step-definitions)
2. [File types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131653/intellij-idea-not-recognizing-feature-files)
3. [Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869851/intellij-with-cucumber-java-and-step-definition-location/40384015)

This is Maven project, I got following doubts

1. Should I add `info.cukes` to project `POM` despite of having plugin in the IDE. Even one of my Gradle project also facing the same issue.
2. Is this mandatory, if so why. Because I can't find `cucumber.api.cli.main` to set in the Main Class 
   [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869851/intellij-with-cucumber-java-and-step-definition-location/40384015)

   > You can set the glue location globally by opening "Edit Configurations
   >   -> Defaults -> Cucumber Java -> Glue" and add the package names.
3. What does this mean
   [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869851/intellij-with-cucumber-java-and-step-definition-location/40384015)

   > My project did not have the steps marked as test source root

Can anyone shed some light here please.

Comment: BTW I have some projects where I can step into `StepDef` file from `feature` in the `IDE`. Above happens for some existing projects that I have imported.In fact in those imported projects I have created new step definition file from the scratch from the feature file. Still it's un-recognized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102161/cucumber-undefined-step-though-defined-using-intellij/47263694#47263694  please check if it helps

Comment: I was missing `io.cucumber` libs in the external jars. I had to manually add them as automatic maven update didn't work as expected. After adding them and set the `debug configuration` it identified the steps